# How to serve an image using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a logo that is residing at the `public/images/logo.gif`. Here is my nodejs code.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Hello World \n');
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

It works but when I request for `localhost:8080/logo.gif` then I obviously don't get the logo.

What changes I need to do to serve an image.

Answer (score 334):

## 2016 Update

### Examples with Express and without Express that *actually work*

This question is over 5 years old but **every answer has some problems**.

### TL;DR

Scroll down for examples to serve an image with:

1. `express.static`
2. `express`
3. `connect`
4. `http`
5. `net`

All of the examples are also on GitHub: https://github.com/rsp/node-static-http-servers

Test results are available on Travis: https://travis-ci.org/rsp/node-static-http-servers

### Introduction

After over 5 years since this question was asked there is only [**one correct answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5823807/613198) by **generalhenry** but even though that answer has no problems with the code, it seems to have some problems with **reception**. It was commented that it *"doesn't explain much other than how to rely on someone else to get the job done"* and the fact how many people have voted this comment up clearly shows that a lot of things need clarification.

First of all, a good answer to "How to serve images using Node.js" is not implementing a **static file server from scratch** and doing it badly. A good answer is **using a module** like Express that **does the job correctly**.

Answering comments that say that using Express *"doesn't explain much other than how to rely on someone else to get the job done"* it should be noted, that using the `http` module **already** relies on someone else to get the job done. If someone doesn't want to rely on anyone to get the job done then **at least** raw TCP sockets should be used instead - which I do in one of my examples below.

A more serious problem is that all of the answers here that use the `http` module are **broken**. They introduce **race conditions**, **insecure path resolution** that will lead to **path traversal vulnerability**, **blocking I/O** that will completely **fail to serve any concurrent requests** at all and other subtle problems - they are completely broken as examples of what the question asks about, and yet they already use the abstraction that is provided by the `http` module instead of using TCP sockets so they don't even do everything from scratch as they claim.

If the question was "How to implement static file server from scratch, as a learning exercise" then by all means answers how to do that should be posted - but even then we should expect them to at least be **correct**. Also, it is not unreasonable to assume that someone who wants to serve an image might want to serve more images in the future so one could argue that writing a specific custom static file server that can serve only one single file with hard-coded path is somewhat shortsighted. It seems hard to imagine that anyone who searches for an answer on how to serve an image would be content with a solution that serves just a single image instead of a general solution to serve any image.

In short, the question is how to serve an image and an answer to that is to use an appropriate module to do that in a **secure, performant and reliable way** that is **readable, maintainable and future-proof** while using the **best practice** of professional Node development. But I agree that a great addition to such an answer would be showing a way to implement the same functionality manually but sadly every attempt to do that has failed so far. And that is why I wrote some new examples.

After this short introduction, here are my five examples doing the job on 5 different levels of abstraction.

### Minimum functionality

Every example serves files from the `public` directory and supports the minimum functionality of:

- MIME types for most common files
- serves HTML, JS, CSS, plain text and images
- serves `index.html` as a default directory index
- responds with error codes for missing files
- no path traversal vulnerabilities
- no race conditions while reading files

I tested every version on Node versions 4, 5, 6 and 7.

### `express.static`

This version uses the [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) built-in middleware of the [`express`](https://expressjs.com/) module.

This example has the most functionality and the least amount of code.

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

app.use(express.static(dir));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

### `express`

This version uses the [`express`](https://expressjs.com/) module but without the `express.static` middleware. Serving static files is implemented as a single route handler using streams.

This example has simple path traversal countermeasures and supports a limited set of most [`common MIME types`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

var mime = {
    html: 'text/html',
    txt: 'text/plain',
    css: 'text/css',
    gif: 'image/gif',
    jpg: 'image/jpeg',
    png: 'image/png',
    svg: 'image/svg+xml',
    js: 'application/javascript'
};

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    var file = path.join(dir, req.path.replace(/\/$/, '/index.html'));
    if (file.indexOf(dir + path.sep) !== 0) {
        return res.status(403).end('Forbidden');
    }
    var type = mime[path.extname(file).slice(1)] || 'text/plain';
    var s = fs.createReadStream(file);
    s.on('open', function () {
        res.set('Content-Type', type);
        s.pipe(res);
    });
    s.on('error', function () {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(404).end('Not found');
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

### `connect`

This version uses the [`connect`](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect) module which is a one level of abstraction lower than `express`.

This example has similar functionality to the `express` version but using slightly lower-lever APIs.

```
var path = require('path');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect();
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

var mime = {
    html: 'text/html',
    txt: 'text/plain',
    css: 'text/css',
    gif: 'image/gif',
    jpg: 'image/jpeg',
    png: 'image/png',
    svg: 'image/svg+xml',
    js: 'application/javascript'
};

app.use(function (req, res) {
    var reqpath = req.url.toString().split('?')[0];
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        res.statusCode = 501;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        return res.end('Method not implemented');
    }
    var file = path.join(dir, reqpath.replace(/\/$/, '/index.html'));
    if (file.indexOf(dir + path.sep) !== 0) {
        res.statusCode = 403;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        return res.end('Forbidden');
    }
    var type = mime[path.extname(file).slice(1)] || 'text/plain';
    var s = fs.createReadStream(file);
    s.on('open', function () {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', type);
        s.pipe(res);
    });
    s.on('error', function () {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end('Not found');
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

### `http`

This version uses the [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http) module which is the lowest-level API for HTTP in Node.

This example has similar functionality to the `connect` version but using even more lower-level APIs.

```
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

var mime = {
    html: 'text/html',
    txt: 'text/plain',
    css: 'text/css',
    gif: 'image/gif',
    jpg: 'image/jpeg',
    png: 'image/png',
    svg: 'image/svg+xml',
    js: 'application/javascript'
};

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var reqpath = req.url.toString().split('?')[0];
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        res.statusCode = 501;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        return res.end('Method not implemented');
    }
    var file = path.join(dir, reqpath.replace(/\/$/, '/index.html'));
    if (file.indexOf(dir + path.sep) !== 0) {
        res.statusCode = 403;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        return res.end('Forbidden');
    }
    var type = mime[path.extname(file).slice(1)] || 'text/plain';
    var s = fs.createReadStream(file);
    s.on('open', function () {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', type);
        s.pipe(res);
    });
    s.on('error', function () {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end('Not found');
    });
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

### `net`

This version uses the [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net) module which is the lowest-level API for TCP sockets in Node.

This example has some of the functionality of the `http` version but the minimal and incomplete HTTP protocol has been implemented from scratch. Since it doesn't support chunked encoding it loads the files into memory before serving them to know the size before sending a response because statting the files and then loading would introduce a race condition.

```
var path = require('path');
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

var mime = {
    html: 'text/html',
    txt: 'text/plain',
    css: 'text/css',
    gif: 'image/gif',
    jpg: 'image/jpeg',
    png: 'image/png',
    svg: 'image/svg+xml',
    js: 'application/javascript'
};

var server = net.createServer(function (con) {
    var input = '';
    con.on('data', function (data) {
        input += data;
        if (input.match(/\n\r?\n\r?/)) {
            var line = input.split(/\n/)[0].split(' ');
            var method = line[0], url = line[1], pro = line[2];
            var reqpath = url.toString().split('?')[0];
            if (method !== 'GET') {
                var body = 'Method not implemented';
                con.write('HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented\n');
                con.write('Content-Type: text/plain\n');
                con.write('Content-Length: '+body.length+'\n\n');
                con.write(body);
                con.destroy();
                return;
            }
            var file = path.join(dir, reqpath.replace(/\/$/, '/index.html'));
            if (file.indexOf(dir + path.sep) !== 0) {
                var body = 'Forbidden';
                con.write('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\n');
                con.write('Content-Type: text/plain\n');
                con.write('Content-Length: '+body.length+'\n\n');
                con.write(body);
                con.destroy();
                return;
            }
            var type = mime[path.extname(file).slice(1)] || 'text/plain';
            var s = fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    var body = 'Not Found';
                    con.write('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n');
                    con.write('Content-Type: text/plain\n');
                    con.write('Content-Length: '+body.length+'\n\n');
                    con.write(body);
                    con.destroy();
                } else {
                    con.write('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n');
                    con.write('Content-Type: '+type+'\n');
                    con.write('Content-Length: '+data.byteLength+'\n\n');
                    con.write(data);
                    con.destroy();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

### Download examples

I posted all of the examples on GitHub with more explanation.

Examples with `express.static`, `express`, `connect`, `http` and `net`:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-static-http-servers

Other project using only `express.static`:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-express-static-example

### Tests

Test results are available on Travis:

- https://travis-ci.org/rsp/node-static-http-servers

Everything is tested on Node versions 4, 5, 6, and 7.

### See also

Other related answers:

- [Failed to load resource from same directory when redirecting Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441863/failed-to-load-resource-from-same-directory-when-redirecting-javascript/38442747#38442747)
- [onload js call not working with node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587286/onload-js-call-not-working-with-node/38587729#38587729)
- [Sending whole folder content to client with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509666/sending-whole-folder-content-to-client-with-express/40510339#40510339)
- [Loading partials fails on the server JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722476/loading-partials-fails-on-the-server-js/40722594#40722594)
- [Node JS not serving the static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837359/node-js-not-serving-the-static-image/40839534#40839534)

Comment: There should be a way to way to revamp vintage questions such as this! I just wasted an hour or so trying to get the 110 vote response to work. Finally I scrolled down just to check. Your answer could (should) be a textbook on the topic.

Comment: I do not know why anyone would use Express. I did too at the start probably because everyone else did. Then I realized that using Node's http module is the right approach. That is what it is provided for.  You get a lot of flexibility. You understand HTTP protocol and you can debug easily.  Express provides a lot of jargon and a thin layer over the http module which is easy to implement with raw coding with the http module. **I strongly recommend any user of Express or any other such module to move away from them and use http module directly.**

Comment: Great answer. But I have a question. If the image is very big, if it's possible to serve the image with multipart? Any example? Thanks.

Comment: a note i would like to mention for newbies like me: when we declare a folder as static using `express.static` we can fetch the image by calling the url `http://ip:port/path_after_the_static_folder` ,we do not need to mention the static folder itself to serve the image. Though we can add that by using `app.use('/static', express.static(imagePath))` for convenience as par documentation in: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: also if there are nested folders, they are needed to be declared as static using `espress.static` too for those paths to be served for images or other files.

Comment: Nice coverage in this answer, going progressively lower in abstractions is a good approach. It's a good resource for me; if you're curious to hear why people are reading this kind of stuff, personally I'm starting with node.js but I might eventually implement some html status pages on very low spec, esoteric hardware that can't even run javascript. Both the client and server will be weak computers on a LAN (no internet access).

Comment: The 1st answer (`express.static`) still works in 2019 with `node` version `10.8.0` and `express@4.17.1`

Comment: The reason people are asking for an answer that doesn't involve express is that they want to understand how node works, at the level of Node without a framework. Those same people would probably also be happy to learn how TCP sockets work. Those who enjoy to write code, enjoy understanding, and learning a framework generally gives a person the information needed to get the job done, but not the information needed to understand how that job is getting done. It is more than just understanding 'HOW', it is the understanding  'WHY'.

Comment: I use this answer to practice using some of the above libraries in my studies.

Answer (score 178):

I agree with the other posters that eventually, you should use a framework, such as Express.. but first you should also understand how to do something fundamental like this without a library, to really understand what the library abstracts away for you..   The steps are

1. Parse the incoming HTTP request, to see which path the user is asking for
2. Add a pathway in conditional statement for the server to respond to
3. If the image is requested, read the image file from the disk.
4. Serve the image content-type in a header
5. Serve the image contents in the body

The code would look something like this (not tested)

```
fs = require('fs');
http = require('http');
url = require('url');


http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var request = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var action = request.pathname;

  if (action == '/logo.gif') {
     var img = fs.readFileSync('./logo.gif');
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif' });
     res.end(img, 'binary');
  } else { 
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
     res.end('Hello World \n');
  }
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: You shouldn't use readFileSync in the middle of a response. Either a sync load should be used on the first tic or the async method should be used. codr.cc/s/5d0b73d6/js

Comment: I'm on board with you on the sync version, for the async version though, I thought the danger of using non-blocking operations for files, was that it could send the response before the entire file was read, and end up leaving you with a partial file being served to the user?  Do you need to use chunked encoding if you use an async file read?

Comment: fs.readFileSync doesn't callback until the whole file is loaded so there's no need for chunk handling.  Chunk handling is mostly for network file transfer (since things can take longer than expected).

Comment: The line `res.end(img);` should be `res.end(img, 'binary');`. Good work!

Comment: You should also know what the framework does, because sometimes it's just easier for simpler sites and although its more complex, bigger sites will be more customizable. The main advantage is if express doesn't help you in certain scenarios, you can just code native http server instead of looking through forums and documentation.

Comment: res.end() doesn't work `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'res.end()')`

Comment: +1 for "but first you should also understand how to do something fundamental like this without a library, to really understand what the library abstracts away for you.."

Comment: You should **never** use any blocking (Sync) function in any callback. Doing so results in serious problems. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767) for examples on how to implement static server with pure `http` (and even without it) with no blocking operations at all.

Comment: @holms If you want something that works then see the examples in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767). All of them are tested with Travis on Node versions 4, 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: seems like a production approach would be to put something like FastCGI infront of NodeJS to serve all those static files, right?

Answer (score 87):

You should use the [express](http://expressjs.com/) framework.

```
npm install express
```

and then

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8080);
```

and then the URL **localhost:8080/images/logo.gif** should work.

Comment: Safe, but doesn't explain much other than how to rely on someone else to get the job done.

Comment: I added a vanilla node (just core modules) version.

Comment: +I This is the only correct answer posted so far. I explain it in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767) in more details.

Answer (score 29):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'image/jpg'});
  fs.createReadStream('./image/demo.jpg').pipe(res);
}).listen(3000);
console.log('server running at 3000');
```

Comment: simple and to the point, way better than the express answers.. this deserves 1000 upvotes. Just a tip: maybe remove the code snippet and replace it with just javascript text

Comment: would it be possible to pass a parameter so that './image/:jpg can serve any picture?

Comment: @Prav kind of I used query params, but then you need some kind of regex to check for it, like so ```const { url} = req;
    if (url.match(/^\/img.+/)) {
      const name = url.split("name=").pop();
    }```

Answer (score 19):

It is too late but helps someone, I'm using `node version v7.9.0` and `express version 4.15.0`

if your directory structure is something like this:

```
your-project
   uploads
   package.json
   server.js
```

server.js code:

```
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));// you can access image 
 //using this url: http://localhost:7000/abc.jpg
//make sure `abc.jpg` is present in `uploads` dir.

//Or you can change the directory for hiding real directory name:

`app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname+'/uploads/'));// you can access image using this url: http://localhost:7000/images/abc.jpg


app.listen(7000);
```

Comment: Was trying to access a static folder using "http://localhost:7000/uploads/abc.jpg". Thank you for your comment about removing the folder and just using "http://localhost:7000/abc.jpg"

Answer (score 14):

Vanilla node version as requested:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // parse url
  var request = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var action = request.pathname;
  // disallow non get requests
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    res.writeHead(405, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('405 Method Not Allowed');
    return;
  }
  // routes
  if (action === '/') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World \n');
    return;
  }
  // static (note not safe, use a module for anything serious)
  var filePath = path.join(__dirname, action).split('%20').join(' ');
  fs.exists(filePath, function (exists) {
    if (!exists) {
       // 404 missing files
       res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
       res.end('404 Not Found');
       return;
    }
    // set the content type
    var ext = path.extname(action);
    var contentType = 'text/plain';
    if (ext === '.gif') {
       contentType = 'image/gif'
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType });
    // stream the file
    fs.createReadStream(filePath, 'utf-8').pipe(res);
  });
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: You don't want to check for `fs.exists` (race condition), it'd be a better habit to catch an error when piping.

Comment: Though checking exists in this case isn't the node way, everything else about this answer is 1 million times better than the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with @BrendanAshworth. The race conditions are present in almost all of the answers here. I wrote more about it in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767). But Kudos for writing it with streams. Almost all other answers use readFileSync which is blocking and should not be used in any event handlers.

Comment: var filePath = path.resolve('public', '.' + parts.pathname);    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mime.lookup(parts.pathname)});         mime - package mime-type from npm

Answer (score 13):

I like using [Restify](https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify) for REST services. In my case, I had created a REST service to serve up images and then if an image source returned 404/403, I wanted to return an alternative image.  Here's what I came up with combining some of the stuff here:

```
function processRequest(req, res, next, url) {
    var httpOptions = {
        hostname: host,
        path: url,
        port: port,
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var reqGet = http.request(httpOptions, function (response) {
        var statusCode = response.statusCode;

        // Many images come back as 404/403 so check explicitly
        if (statusCode === 404 || statusCode === 403) {
            // Send default image if error
            var file = 'img/user.png';
            fs.stat(file, function (err, stat) {
                var img = fs.readFileSync(file);
                res.contentType = 'image/png';
                res.contentLength = stat.size;
                res.end(img, 'binary');
            });

        } else {
            var idx = 0;
            var len = parseInt(response.header("Content-Length"));
            var body = new Buffer(len);

            response.setEncoding('binary');

            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                body.write(chunk, idx, "binary");
                idx += chunk.length;
            });

            response.on('end', function () {
                res.contentType = 'image/jpg';
                res.send(body);
            });

        }
    });

    reqGet.on('error', function (e) {
        // Send default image if error
        var file = 'img/user.png';
        fs.stat(file, function (err, stat) {
            var img = fs.readFileSync(file);
            res.contentType = 'image/png';
            res.contentLength = stat.size;
            res.end(img, 'binary');
        });
    });

    reqGet.end();

    return next();
}
```

Comment: You should **never** use readFileSync inside of event handlers. This is a synchronous operation that blocks your entire process while it reads the file. I explained it in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767) in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a bit off-topic, since you are asking about static file serving via Node.js specifically (where `fs.createReadStream('./image/demo.jpg').pipe(res)` is actually a good idea), but in production you may want to have your Node app handle tasks, that cannot be tackled otherwise, and off-load static serving to e.g Nginx.

This means less coding inside your app, and better efficiency since reverse proxies are by design ideal for this.

Answer (score 3):

This method works for me, it's not dynamic but straight to the point:

```
const fs      = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();

app.get( '/logo.gif', function( req, res ) {

  fs.readFile( 'logo.gif', function( err, data ) {

    if ( err ) {

      console.log( err );
      return;
    }

    res.write( data );
    return res.end();
  });

});

app.listen( 80 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me just add to the answers above, that optimizing images, and serving responsive images helps page loading times dramatically since >90% of web traffic are images. You might want to **pre-process images using JS / Node modules** such as [imagemin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin#readme) and related plug-ins, ideally during the build process with Grunt or [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/).

**Optimizing images** means processing finding an ideal image type, and selecting optimal compression to achieve a balance between image quality and file size.

**Serving responsive images** translates into creating several sizes and formats of each image automatically and using `srcset` in your HTML allows you to serve optimal image set (that is, the ideal format and dimensions, thus optimal file size) for every single browser).

**Image processing automation** during the build process means incorporating it up once, and presenting optimized images further on, requiring minimum extra time.

Some great read on [responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images), [minification](https://netwell.digital/minification/) in general, [imagemin](https://web.dev/use-imagemin-to-compress-images/) node module and  [using srcset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp).

Answer (score 2):

```js
//This method involves directly integrating HTML Code in the res.write
//first time posting to stack ...pls be kind

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const https = require('https');

app.get("/",function(res,res){
    res.write("<img src="+image url / src +">");
    res.send();
});

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
  console.log("the server is onnnn");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import http from "node:http";
import fs from "node:fs";

http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    if(req.url === "/" && req.method === "GET"){
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type" : "image/jpg"
        })
        fs.readFile("someimage.jpg", (err, data)=>{
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
             res.write(data);
             res.end();
        })
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P, thanks for letting me know brother, I will add information

Answer (score 0):

Does express support HTTP/3? Nope.

How about HTTP/2? Nope.

I guess future proof didn't work out.

The problem of depending on a module that isn't updated quickly when standards change. Be advised.