# Failed to load resource from same directory when redirecting Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am writing an application in NodeJS.

I have two files in the same directory but whenever I call either:

```js
window.location.href = "./page.html";


window.location.href = "/page.html";
```

from my index.html I get a failed to load resource error.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it have to do with Node? Can you access both files when you type in the URLs manually?

Comment: When I run it through Node I call:

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

So when I visit the site I go to http://localhost:8000/. I don't really know any other way.

Comment: Use express static middleware to serve static files `app.use(express.static('public'));`, any file in public folder`<your-app>/public/` will be served. See this https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve static files with Express, you should use `express.static` or otherwise you will have to define a new route for every html file that you have, or reinvent the functionality provided by `express.static`. **(If you don't want to use Express for that then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767).)**

You can do something like this:

#### `app.js`

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'html');

app.use(express.static(htmlPath));

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = 'localhost';
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('listening on http://'+host+':'+port+'/');
});
```

Put your files in the `html` subdirectory. For example:

#### `html/index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index.html</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>index.html</h1>
<p>Redirection in 2s...</p>
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "./page.html";
}, 2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### `html/page.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>page.html</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>page.html</h1>
<p>Redirection in 2s...</p>
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "./index.html";
}, 2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the files will redirect every 2 seconds.

You can download this example from GitHub:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-express-static-example

More examples to do the same with and without Express:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-static-http-servers

Other related answers:

- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)
- [onload js call not working with node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587286/onload-js-call-not-working-with-node/38587729#38587729)
- [Sending whole folder content to client with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509666/sending-whole-folder-content-to-client-with-express/40510339#40510339)
- [Loading partials fails on the server JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722476/loading-partials-fails-on-the-server-js/40722594#40722594)
- [Node JS not serving the static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837359/node-js-not-serving-the-static-image/40839534#40839534)