# onload js call not working with node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am starting to learn node.js, for now I am just trying to execute my old none node app with node. In this app, I have a html page with a body calling an onload js function. It's working just fine.

Now I have a a node app: app.js, simple as that:

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express ();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/CSS'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/font'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname ));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/ketcher'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/ChemAlive_JS'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.sendFile('/home/laetitia/Project/ChemAlive_Interface_Node/ChemAlive_Interface.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

And in the .html I still have:

```
<body onload="ketcher.init();">
```

but the function I want to load is not load at all anymore.

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Where does this function exist

Comment: In a js file in one of the dir set by static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided a lot of info in the question but from what you provide I can have few suggestions:

### Suggestions

Instead of adding a lot of `express.static` uses:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/CSS'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/font'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname ));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/ketcher'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/ChemAlive_JS'));
```

put those files (and directories) that you want to be served into one directory, e.g. called `static`, and use `express.static` once:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

or better yet, using the `path` module:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```

you need to require the `path` module first with:

```
var path = require('path');
```

Now, instead of serving the single file for the `'/'` route with:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/home/laetitia/Project/ChemAlive_Interface_Node/ChemAlive_Interface.html');
});
```

just put that file into the `static` directory as index.html so it will be served by the `express.static` middleware automatically.

### Rationale

The way you have it configured currently, is that e.g. everyone can download your Node application - `app.js` with all of its configuration and even submodules etc.

Also, by using the `express.static` middleware many times I suspect that you are not sure how the files in those directories will be mapped to URLs.

Having a one place for static files makes it easy to verify whether any script tags have correct paths etc.

### My guess

You don't provide enough info to be sure but my guess is that the JavaScript files for the main HTML file are not loaded correctly but you provide not enough info to be sure.

You can open the developer tools console in the browser and reload the page while the console is open and see for errors.

I suspect that the `ketcher.init()` method is being run but either the method, or the `ketcher` object is undefined, because some `<script>` tags failed to be loaded.

### Example

The full example after following my suggestions would be much simpler:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.listen(8080);
```

Maybe I would add some output to see what's going on:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require ('express');
console.log('starting app.js');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('listening on http://localhost:8080/');
});
```

And now you will have all files that can be served to the browser in one place: in the `static` directory in this example.

### Working app

You can see my example of a working Express application serving static files on GitHub:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-express-static-example

In this example the directory for static files is called `html` but you can call it how you want, as long as it's consistent with how you use the `express.static` middleware.

You can start from this example project and just put your own files into the directory where `express.static` is told to look for files to serve.

You can also change the port number to match your needs.

More examples to do the same with and without Express, plus better explanation:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-static-http-servers

### More hints

The onload callback may not be fired if the page is waiting for some resources to load.

To see if your onload callback is firing you can change it to:

```
<body onload="alert('onload callback fired');">
```

Also the `ketcher` object may be not initialized or it may not have the `init()` method. After the page is loaded you can open the JavaScript Console and try running the method manually to see if it would work if it was fired:

```
ketcher.init();
```

You can also try commands like:

```
console.dir(ketcher.init);
console.dir(ketcher);
console.log(typeof ketcher.init);
console.log(typeof ketcher);
```

to see if the `ketcher` object contains what it should.

Even if the `GET localhost:8080/ketcher.js` gives a 200 OK status, it can still load some other resources that are not available or, as is very common with code that serve files with `res.sendFile()` (though unlikely in this case), it can serve HTML instead of JavaScript and result in a cryptic parse error on the `<` character - see this question for example:

- [Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while acess static files in node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520688/uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-whil/44521141#44521141)

Other related answers:

- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)
- [Failed to load resource from same directory when redirecting Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441863/failed-to-load-resource-from-same-directory-when-redirecting-javascript/38442747#38442747)
- [Sending whole folder content to client with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509666/sending-whole-folder-content-to-client-with-express/40510339#40510339)
- [Loading partials fails on the server JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722476/loading-partials-fails-on-the-server-js/40722594#40722594)
- [Node JS not serving the static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837359/node-js-not-serving-the-static-image/40839534#40839534)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll do what you suggest to simplify the organisaton of my app. However I am sure the problem is not there but specifically on the onload function because I have then in the html a lot of button connected to js that are working just fine. It's just the onload that is not executed.

Comment: Also in the console I can see this line when I load the page: "GET 
http://localhost:8080/ketcher.js" and this is the file where the init function I what to load is, so I guess it's not a file location problem

Comment: @Laetis See my updated answer - the "More hints" section - for a possible way to see if the onload handler is fired or not, and to test if it would be ok if it was fired, by running the `init()` manually.