# Sending whole folder content to client with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, game-maker

I made an html5 game (using GameMaker), which is constituted of an index.html and a folder "html5game" that contains the dependencies of the game - the javascript code and the resources. The problem is the resources are quite numerous and diverse (sounds, sprites, etc.) and The client needs them all to play.

I am looking for a way to send them all without naming them specifically.

I tried the glob module :

```
var glob = require( 'glob' );    

var files = glob.sync( './html5game/**' ).forEach( function( file ) {
      require( path.resolve( file ) );
});
```

but I can't figure a way to send the files using res.sendFile() once I did that.

I tried

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();   

[...]

app.get('/aeronavale/jeu', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/aeronavale/index.html');
        res.sendFile(files)

});

[...]

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('app started on port 3000, yeah !')
})
```

but it gives me the error :

```
TypeError: path argument is required to res.sendFile
```

If you have an other solution, I a also interested. Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will not be able to send multiple file like that with `res.sendFile`. The most straightforward thing that you can do here would be this:

Put your `index.html` file and your `html5game` directory into some common directory, e.g. called `html` and put it where you have your Node.js program. An example directory layout would be:

```
/home/you/yourapp:
- app.js (your node program)
- package.json (your package.json etc)
- html (a new directory)
  - index.html (your main html to serve)
  - html5game (the directory with other files)
    - (other files)
```

Now, in your Node program you can use something like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'html');

app.use(express.static(htmlPath));

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = 'localhost';
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('listening on http://'+host+':'+port+'/');
});
```

This will serve all of your files (including `index.html`) on addresses like:

- http://localhost:3000/ (your `index.html`)
- http://localhost:3000/html5game/xxx.js (your assets)

Of course you still need to make sure that you refer to your assets in your `index.html` file correctly, for example with:

```
<script src="/html5game/xxx.js"></script>
```

in the case of the example layout above.

The top level directory with your static assets (where you have your `index.html`) is usually called `static`, `public` or `html` but you can call it whatever you like, as long as you use the correct path in your call to `express.static()`.

If you want to have your game available in some path other than the root path then you can specify it to `app.use`. For example if you change this:

```
app.use(express.static(htmlPath));
```

to this:

```
app.use('/game', express.static(htmlPath));
```

Then instead of those URLs:

- http://localhost:3000/ (your `index.html`)
- http://localhost:3000/html5game/xxx.js (your assets)

those URLs will be available instead:

- http://localhost:3000/game/ (your `index.html`)
- http://localhost:3000/game/html5game/xxx.js (your assets)

A lot of questions here are related to serving static files with Express so I made a working example and posted it on GitHub so that people could have a working starting point and go from there:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-express-static-example

See also some other answers where I talk about it in more detail:

- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)
- [Failed to load resource from same directory when redirecting Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441863/failed-to-load-resource-from-same-directory-when-redirecting-javascript/38442747#38442747)
- [onload js call not working with node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587286/onload-js-call-not-working-with-node/38587729#38587729)
- [Loading partials fails on the server JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722476/loading-partials-fails-on-the-server-js/40722594#40722594)
- [Node JS not serving the static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837359/node-js-not-serving-the-static-image/40839534#40839534)

Comment: Thanks, I test that and come back to validate soon

Comment: So, with this solution, I have to create a folder structure that is the one I want on the server and each has to contain an index.html ?

Comment: @Aninternhasnoname Yes, you can create the structure that you want on the server - e.g. with the `html` directory containing `game1`, `game2` etc. each having its own `index.html` and a subdirectory with assets - that would be the easiest one with one call to `app.use(express.static(htmlPath));` - or alternatively you may have one call per game: `app.use('/game1', express.static(pathToGame1Files));` and `app.use('/game2', express.static(pathToGame2Files));` whichever seems more convenient for you. You may even mix the two ways but the order of registering the paths will matter.

Comment: Thank you very much !
If you are curious, here is the game I just uploaded :
http://lapinou.dnet.ovh:3000/aeronavale/jeu/

use arrows and X, I didn't make  tutorial yet :)
(if you read this long fter the comment was posted, be aware the link may not be avalaible forever)

Comment: @Aninternhasnoname This is a very cool game! :) It reminds me of a great DOS game Wings of Fury - only yours is on steroids and much harder. ;) Very cool. Drop me a line on twitter when you have it finished with tutorial - I'm [@pocztarski](https://twitter.com/pocztarski) on twitter. Keep up the good work! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Of course, I'll tell you when I have a complete version. Thanks for all !

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for this is to compress the directory using the [archiver library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) and uncompress it on the front end.