# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while acess static files in node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

Hi i am developing small application using react create app with node in thatis application i want to acess static file in node  i use like this

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/", 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

but i am getting getting error

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are serving the same file for every request - also for the scripts required by the original HTML page. The browser request script, it gets HTML and the parser fails on `<` of `<doctype>` or `<html>`.

You can see in the Network tab of your browser's developer console all of the requests that your browser is making - I can bet that you're requesting something like `script.js` and instead of JavaScript contents you get the HTML contents of your `index.html` file.

It seems that you're using Express. Use `express.static` to serve static files instead of `res.sendFile()`

Since it seems that you have every static file in `build`, use something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'build');

app.use(express.static(dir));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

This is the entire program that you need. Of course you can change the port number.

It will serve your `index.html` correctly but it will also serve all of the other assets like images, client-side scripts required with `<script>`, CSS files etc. plus also other HTML files if there are any.

If you don't want to use Express then see this answer for more options of serving files:

- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)

Comment: If I used app.use(express.static(dir)) it is working fine for Home page(http://localhost:3000/) and Admin  (http://localhost:3000/admin)  but i deploy in server it works for Home page  when i move to admin page it through 502 Bad Gateway  in server i used nginx