# Express NodeJS Cannot find module 'html'

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node Server with Express. I get the cannot find module 'html' error even though my code looks like this and should be correct in my opinion:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'build/views'));
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "build/favicon.ico")));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `engine` for `HTML`

Include this code in your main file

```
var engines = require('consolidate');

app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Comment: I just quickly changed it to: 
`res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/views/index.html'));`
Would this be a nice solution as well or is your solution better/ nicer?

Comment: It depends on writing of code structure. Mostly we prefer 'views' to get 'static' pages

Comment: Yes if you are using Angular then it can't work since angular work on client site and doesn't work on server side

Comment: What do you mean? I am using NodeJS as a Server and then for the frontEnd I use HTML + AngularJS + CSS + Javascript. And it worked before as well. Before I just had view engine = jade. Should not be a big difference?

Comment: The problem is when you use mustache you can pass variables which are recognised by {{}}. AngularJS also does that, but somehow mustache has a higher priority which results in empty variables. A solution would be to change the startSymbol to [[ and end Symbol to ]] for AngularJS

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to serve a static file without passing any variables from the server to the client the easiest solution would be:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/views/index.html'));
```

Especially when you are using AngularJS for the client side. The problem with the solution above is that mustache uses {{}} as variables recognition. So does AngularJS which might causes errors!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to display a static `index.html` file but you serve it as if it was a template. Probably Express is trying to find a module for `html` template format, which doesn't exist.

You may try to send the index as a static file instead of with `res.render` which is for rendering templates.

Some time ago I wrote an example of serving static files with Express. It's available on GitHub:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-express-static-example

See also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441863/failed-to-load-resource-from-same-directory-when-redirecting-javascript/38442747#38442747), where I explain it in more detail.