# ( NodeJS ) Http server does not load JS/CSS files from folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

Good day ,

I've got a small problem with my NodeJS http server. The server doesn't load the CSS/JS files from folder , only from url and i don't know why. I would appreciate if someone could take some time and give me some tips on what went wrong.

Here is the Server Code :

```
var http = require("http");
var gs = require("querystring");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response, err) {

//HTML
if (request.url === "/") {
    sendFileContent(response, "HTML/Login.html", "text/html");
    console.log("Requested URL : " + request.url + "\n");
}
else if (request.url === "/main") {
    sendFileContent(response, "HTML/Main_Home.html", "text/html");
    console.log("Requested URL : " + request.url + "\n");
}
// JS / CSS / Other formats
else if (/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*.js$/.test(request.url.toString(1))) {
    sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "text/javascript");
}
else if (/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*.css$/.test(request.url.toString())) 
{        
    sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "text/css");
}
else if (/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*.json$/.test(request.url.toString())) 
{
    sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "application/json");
}
else if (/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*.ts$/.test(request.url.toString())) 
{
    sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "text/javascript");
}
else if (/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*.png$/.test(request.url.toString())) 
{
    sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "image/png");
}
else if (/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*.jpg$/.test(request.url.toString())) 
{
    sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "image/jpeg");
}
else 
{
    console.log("Requested URL : " + request.url + "\n");
    response.end();
}
});

server.listen(1337, function () 
{ 
  require("console-stamp")(console, '[HH:MM:ss]');
  console.log("HTTP Server runs on port : 1337");

});

console.log("Server ready....");
```

And here is the `Send file content` function :

```
function sendFileContent(response, fileName, contentType){
fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, data) { 
    if (err) {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end("Not Found!");
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": contentType });
        response.end(data);
    }

});
};
```

And this is how i call the files in html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../materialize/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/App.css" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../materialize/js/materialize.min.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Javascript/Main_App.js"></script>
```

Thank you for your time !

Comment: did you attempt browsing directly to one of said files? likely cause is due to incorrect path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implement your own static files server and there so many problems in your implementation even besides those that you're asking about that I think that you need to rethink your approach.

To serve static files it is much easier to use a working solution like `express.static` - but read below for solutions without Express if you really need it. Example with `express.static`:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

app.use(express.static(dir));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

See this answer for more options using connect, express, http and net:

- **[How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)**

In that answer there are examples of doing what you're trying to do here using `express.static`, Express without `express.static`, using `connect`,  using `http` and using `net` and even the version that uses raw TCP sockets is not as complicated as your code here. You may want to take a look at it and base your code on [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767).