# How to use User Authentication with node.js

Tags: node.js

I try to practice using User Authentication.

But it cannot work as I expected.

I expected that it can show the login interface to me.

STEPS:

1.use localhost:12345/login_page to connect the server

2.then show the login interface to me

3.key in the username and password

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var app = express();

app.use(cookieSession({
    secret: 'session',
    keys: 'node'
}));

app.get('/login_page', function(req, res){
    if(!req.session.logined){
        res.send('<a href="http://127.0.0.1:12345/logout">Logout Now</a>');
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    res.send('<form action="http://localhost:12345/login" method="POST">');
    res.send('<input type="text" name="username">');
    res.send('<br/>');
    res.send('<input type="password" name="password">');
    res.send('<br/>');
    res.send('<input type="submit" value="login">');
    res.send('</form>');
    res.end();
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    if(res.body.username != 'user' || 
       req.body.password != '12345678'){

        res.send('Account or password error, please login again');
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    res.session.logined = true;
    res.redirect('/login_page');
    res.end();
});

app.post('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.logined = false;
    res.redirect('/login');
    res.end();
});

app.listen(12345);
```

Comment: You can't use `res.send` twice. you should send the login page as a `html` file.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change:

```
res.session.logined = true;
```

to:

```
req.session.logined = true;
```

Also, change `res.send()` to `res.write()`.

Use the body parser.

Change `res.body` to `req.body`.

And change content type to `text/html`.

Those may not even be all of the bugs in that program but those are the most obvious ones. Considering that you have problems implementing that yourself, you might be better off using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/), in particular using the [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) strategy in your case, as it would handle a lot of that logic for you. Here is a good tutorial:

- http://www.codexpedia.com/node-js/node-js-authentication-using-passport-local-strategy/

And for hosting static files, like HTML, see this answer:

- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)

Comment: Sorry, I made a very serious mistake.  The information you shared gave me great help.  Now I solve the problem.  Thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes here.
First of all, you cannot use the `res.send()` function more than once per request, and you don't have to use `res.end` in the end.

So, your code shall look similar to this:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var app = express();

app.use(cookieSession({
    secret: 'session',
    keys: 'node'
}));

app.get('/login_page', function(req, res){
    if(!req.session.logined){
        res.send('<a href="/logout">Logout Now</a>');
    }
    res.send('<form action="/login" method="POST">  <input type="text" name="username"><br/><input type="password" name="password"><br/><input type="submit" value="login"></form>');
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    if(res.body.username != 'user' || 
       req.body.password != '12345678'){

        res.send('Account or password error, please login again');
    }
    req.session.logined = true;
    res.redirect('/login_page');
});

app.post('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.logined = false;
    res.redirect('/login');
});

app.listen(12345);
```

And obviously, for better practice, you should send your responses with `html` files, using 'res.render`or 'res.sendFile`.

Comment: It can't solve my problem.  But you tell me where is wrong.  Very thanks to you.