# Files not picking up after npm gets npm starts

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to angular js. After running npm start the file is in serving from status(serving from :. /)  it's not picking up the file, eventhough. I have mentioned the file name as index.html. Please help me out to remove this issue.

(BS) Serving files from :. /
(BS)  watching files

No results afterwards....

Comment: Can you show us your project setup?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell you what's wrong in your code when you didn't show even a single line. You didn't even tell which framework you're using or any other relevant info.

To see how to serve files with Node using 5 different ways with example, see this answer:

- **[How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)**

It's not only about images, also HTML, CSS, JS etc. Hopefully it will get you on the right track.