# fs unlink cant find the required path

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following delete function in expressjs but when I try use the path of the element I want to remove it appears as undefined yet I've revised the tutorial and still dont see where the problem is:

```
router.delete('/messagedelete/:empId', function (req, res) {

  Message.remove({empId: req.params.empId}, function(err, message) {
      console.log(message.path);
      console.log("got inside");
    if(err) { 
       return res.send({status: "200", response: "fail"});
    }
      console.log(message.path);
    fs.unlink(message.path, function() {
      res.send ({
        status: "200",
        responseType: "string",
        response: "success"
      });     
    });
 }); 
});
```

I import fs like this at the top of the file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: Are yo getting any error and what is the value of  `console.log(message.path);`?

Comment: No just undefined

Comment: and what is the value of `message`? if null then you need to check your query

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems:

1. You are not handling the errors
2. You don't check what file would get deleted

Change this:

```
fs.unlink(message.path, function() {
  res.send ({
    status: "200",
    responseType: "string",
    response: "success"
  });     
});
```

to:

```
fs.unlink(message.path, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // handle the error - like res.send with status 500 etc.
  }
  res.send ({
    status: "200",
    responseType: "string",
    response: "success"
  });     
});
```

You didn't include any info what is the value of `message.path` but you should never delete anything if you're not 100% sure you know what is the path and here your program has really no idea what it's trying to delete - it could be its own source code or some other important file on the system for all we know.

You should use `path.join()` to join some prefix of where you want to delete the files and the `message.path` that you got, with something like:

```
let filePath = path.join(dir, message.path);
```

where `dir` is a place where you keep the files you want deleted - if you don't do it then you may be deleting files on the entire filesystem. But that's not enough, you actually have to check if the result in `filePath` is not outside of `dir` which it well may be if the `message.path` contained `..` for example. So you also need for example:

```
if (filePath.indexOf(dir + path.sep) !== 0) {
    return res.status(403).end('Forbidden');
}
```

See this answer for more examples and more details on validating paths that you compose with `path.join` and why it's important:

- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)

Comment: But how are you meant to get the file path of a mongodb doc? im not deleting off the computer im interacting with a mongodb I set up

Comment: I removed fs unlink as I dont think its really needed here as the tutorial was a deleting with a express tutorial and didnt really involve mongoose, the methods working fine now ill just have to clean it up a bit, think fs unink was just added more problems then needed