# Get real image path from json response

Tags: javascript, json, api, express

I have a local express server that serves a json file. I also have many image files inside a local folder. The image paths are parts of the json object which I want to show in my DOM. However I get string representation of these image paths as part of response which I can't use. What is the best way to server local images to the frontend from a local server.

**A picture of the issue**:[image]

My server side config:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/img')))
```

My JSON file

```js
{
  "Images": [{
    "title": "First Block",
    "images": ["server/img/bijay.jpg", "server/img/dance.png", "server/img/ocean.jpg"]
  }, {obj2}, {obj3}, {obj4}]
}
```

My client-side code to print image

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="obj in objArray"><img ng-src="{{obj.images[0]}}"></li>
</ul>
// just testing first image
```

**My folder structure:**

[image: images are inside img folder. not shown to save space]

Images are inside the img folder. not shown here to save space

Comment: It seems that the given element represent the absolute path of the image, use can simply use `src` to render Absolute URL.

Comment: it however gives me a 404 status response for (localhost://server/img/xyz.jpg)...I think it's an issue with trying to access files in the server using absolute paths

Comment: you should write the url correctly first..Like http://localhost/server/img/xyz.jpg

Comment: sorry url is correct..the extra '/' is just a typo

Comment: If the problem is not resolved yet. Please do provide your server code handling the images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after a lot of rethinking, I found the solution.

I had defined the 'static' folder in the server as 'server/img'. However, inside the json object, I was assigning the absolute path for the image files again. All I needed to do was '<s>server/image/</s>imgFileName.jpg' to resolve the conflict :))

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments of @Tolsee:

Place the images in a 'public' folder. (/public/img/dance.png)
Then in your express app add the following line:

```
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The images will be available with the following url:

```
localhost:port/img/dance.png
```

You could just serve /server/img and then just use the following:

```
let app = express();
app.use(express.static('/server/img'));

localhost:port/dance.png
```

Some configuration might be needed depending on your project structure.

Comment: ahh i get it. i had the same configuration of serving static files from 'public' folder but the images were inside 'server' folder. So I suppose adding the line app.use(express.static('/server/img')) would be enough..i'll check it now

Comment: I can't put images inside public folder as I need to emulate as if the images come from a server

Comment: What url do you use to retrieve the images? If you still want to acces them with localhost/server/img you have to change to 

    app.use('/server/img',express.static('/server/img'));

Comment: i'm not using url...just the absolute path to files inside the img folder (which is inside server folder)

Comment: So from your front-end you want to access files located on the sever by using the absolute path?
That's not possible by my knowledge. You will always need to do a call to your express server to request the images. Why is accessing them from within the public folder not enough?
There is another thread which might interest you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs)

Comment: yes it seems posible by the way I have done. you just need to assign the specific folder you want as 'static' by `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'yourFolder')));
`