# Node.js + Express: What do I have to serve the specific folder's path to express.static?

Tags: node.js, express

I wrote the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname ));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./dist/index.html');
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

which doesn't work. When open the browser and go to "localhost:3000" I get the error:

> path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Of course the once I fix the line that starts with "app.use..." to:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + "./dist"));
```

then everything works right.

Can you please explain why? What's wrong with giving "express.static" a path of a parent folder of the direct folder of the file sent?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order. Instead of:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname ));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./dist/index.html');
});
```

Try:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './dist/index.html'));
});

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
// OR:
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

Plus use `path.join()` to join paths. You need to require `path` first:

```
var path = require('path');
```

See this answer for more info on serving static files and why `path.join` is important:

- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767#40899767)

Now, your problem was not about `express.static` but about `res.sendFile`. When you changed `express.static` path to a different one, then the file you previously wanted to send with `res.sendFile` was probably found by `express.static` and the handler with `res.sendFile` was not run at all. Before the change, the `express.static` wasn't finding the `index.html` file and was passing the request to the next handler - which had a bad `res.sendFile` invocation. That's why it appeared to solve the problem with the error, because the code causing the error was no longer called.