# progressive web app site cannot be installed: no icon available to display

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, create-react-app, web-manifest

I'm building a progressive web app. I started off with boilerplate from [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). Then I added a web app manifest.

> app/public/manifest.json

```
{
    "short_name": "First Contributions",
    "name": "First Contributions",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-chrome-256x256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#ffffff",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "display": "standalone",
    "start_url": "index.html"
}
```

Linked this to `index.html`

> app/public/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <title>First Contributions</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
      <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').catch(function(ex) {
            console.warn(ex);
            console.warn('(This warning can be safely ignored outside of the production build.)');
          });
        }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I've generated icons using `realfavicongenerator.net` and put them in public directory.

I'm deploying my app using `gh-pages`. When I try to *`Add to homescreen`*, I get the following errors

> - android-chrome-192x192.png:1 GET https://roshanjossey.github.io/android-chrome-192x192.png 404 (Not Found)
> - Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: https://roshanjossey.github.io/android-chrome-192x192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)
> - Site cannot be installed: no icon available to display

I think I'm doing something wrong in webmanifest for icons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your icon paths reference to the root directory.

Change `"src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",` to `"src": "android-chrome-192x192.png",` (without `/` at the beginning).

Comment: In my case I forgot the `binary` option in send, nodejs, I have to do it: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/5826883/7173478` just make sure, fellas, that yall are doing it