# icon downloaded from the manifest was empty or corrupted

Tags: json, progressive-web-apps

So I'm setting up a manifest file for my web app, and need a valid icon for it to work. Following the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest#theme_color) structure, I have provided  multiple icons for my application. Here is my manifest so far:

```
{
  "name": "Tradesolution EPD",
  "short_name": "EPD portal",
  "theme_color": "#007AB5",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "http://localhost:1384/#/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "content/images/favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "144x144"
    },
    {
      "src": "content/images/favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "16x16"
    },
    {
      "src": "content/images/ts-logo.svg",
      "sizes": "72x72"
    },
    {
      "src": "content/images/ts-logo.svg",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "background_color": "#007AB5", 
  "orientation": "portrait" 
}
```

I get the following error in the console trying to add the manifest:

```
Site cannot be installed: 
icon downloaded from the manifest was empty or corrupted
```

Here is my manifest overview from the devtools.

[image]

My manifest.json file is also valid according to the W3C standard manifest [validator](https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/)

UPDATE:
So i updated my manifest with a new image with the following parameters:

```
{
  "src": "content/images/pakningssammensetninger/new-B_diagram.png",
  "sizes": "192x192",
  "type": "image/png"
}
```

[image: icon]

I get the same error message in the console:

```
Site cannot be installed: icon downloaded from the manifest was empty or corrupted
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the path for the images cannot be resolved correctly by the browser.

Be aware that when you use relative paths, like in your example `content/images/ts-logo.svg`, that the path is relative to the manifest.

> If src is a relative URL, the base URL will be the URL of the manifest.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/icons

So if your manifest is served at for example `/content/site.webmanifest`, than the icon is expected to be served from `/content/content/images/ts-logo.svg`.

So either correct the path, or make it absolute like so: `/content/images/ts-logo.svg` (note the slash in the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374037/site-cannot-be-installed-icon-downloaded-from-the-manifest-was-empty-or-corrupt). Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#customize_the_icons), when placing the `src` path of the icon, it must refer to the root directory. You should change the path by removing `/` at the beginning and compile it again.

> Change `"src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png", to "src": "android-chrome-192x192.png",` (without `/` at the beginning).

Hope this helps!

Comment: but none of my file path start with ' / '

Answer (score 1):

To install a PWA in Chrome it must fit a [set of criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#what_are_the_criteria). One of those is that the primary icon be in PNG format.

> - a 192x192 png icon (the icon declarations must include a mime type of image/png)

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but it still doesn't work. See updated post for info.