# NodeJS: reload img src attribute

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, sockets, nginx

**Situation:** I am developing an image processing application written in C++ and I have to show the processed frames through a web-interface by reloading a img DOM src every approx. 1 second, i.e. using:

```
$("#myImage").attr("src", "/myImage.jpg?" + new Date().getTime());
```

My idea is to use the C++ application as a client, and a server socket opened from the web-interface.
Using this approach I could achieve good synchronization for the image update, since I experienced problems while updating the img DOM when the image was incomplete.
So

- 1) Every approx. 30 frames, the C++ application connects to the server socket and tell the web-interface that the img can be updated.
- 2) The web-interface updates the DOM img src without any syncronization error.

Based on these requirements, the following is the solution I developed using nginx and nodejs and my little web development experience.

**nginx config snippet**

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
```

**HTML code**:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<title>Frame viewer</title>

<style>
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: top; }

body 
{
    background-color: #ADACFF;
}

#imageOutputDiv 
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}

#footer 
{
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() 
{
    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('update', function (data)
    {
        $("#debugText").text("Updated: " + new Date().getTime().toString());
        $("#imageOutput").attr('src', '/image/output.jpg?'+ new Date().getTime().toString());
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <div id = "bodyTitle">
        <h2 style = "text-align:center">Frame viewer</h2>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="imageOutputDiv">
        <img id="imageOutput"></img>
    </div>

    <div id="debug">
        <h5 id="debugText"></h5>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <h5 id="footerText">test 1.9.1</h5>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**NodeJS code**

```
var htmlPath = '/var/www/html/index.html';
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
app.listen(5000);

function handler (req, res) 
{
  fs.readFile(htmlPath, function (err, data) 
  {
    if (err)
    {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(data);
  });
}

var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(extsocket) 
{
    extsocket.write('# test server\r\n');
    extsocket.on('data', function (data) 
    {
        if (data.toString() == 'takeimage')
        { 
          console.log("Received: " + data.toString());
           // here I should update DOM debugTxt
          io.emit('update', { update: '*' });
        }
    });
});
server.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

The Javascript sockets code executed by nodejs works fine, because I can test the connection on port 8080 with telnet.
The problem is that the **debugText** is updated correctly while the image **imageOutput** is not visibile, so I suspect I don't have access to it..

If possible, how can I load the image and reload the src attribute correctly ? How do I have to modify my code ?

If you think there are better solutions than using nodejs, I will be happy to read your suggestions.

Comment: Well you told nodejs how to serve up your html file, but you haven't told it how to serve up the image.

Comment: Well that's what I am asking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs)

Comment: Problem Solved.