# HTML Website on Node.js server doesn't show images

Tags: html, node.js

So I'm quite new to this but I think this should be possible to solve.

I use a Raspberry Pi 3 and Node.js to create a website to control the GPIO's. I wrote the website with HTML.

Now I want an image as background behind the switches on the website. If I link an images via url (for example a picture from google) it's no problem.

But if I link a picture that is on the Pi, it won`t show on the Website. It shows the name of the file but doesn't display it. 
I put the image in the same folder as the html file.

here is the html code that i have made:

````
<html>
<head>
<body>

<h1>Control LED light</h1>

<img src="Winkraftanlage.png" alt="Windkraftanlage">
</body>
</head>

<body>
<input id="light" type="checkbox">LED
</body>

```</html>


Thanks a lot in advance.
````

Comment: because you'd *probably* didn't serve the *image*. Here's how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use express to handle all your static files and use ejs template for handling frontend
Import express.js into your app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
Now let node know the path of the public folder :
var publicDir = require('path').join(__dirname,'/public');
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
```

**__dirname gives you the current directory (in this case the root directory in which app.js resides for me)**

Now node will serve static files from the above mentioned directory whenever such a URL is accessed, eg.

```
http://localhost/myapp/public/imgs/myImage.jpg
```

Just put the appropriate URL in the src of  on your front-end, like so :

rename your index.html to index.ejs

in your app.js

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

and finally do run `npm install`

and paste your image like this:

```
<img src="public/imgs/Winkraftanlage.png" alt="Windkraftanlage"">
```