# Serve image using s3 and express in lambda project

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a bucket where i save all my user related files and i want the user to be able to download those files, the problem i have is that i need to proxy the petition via an api url like

`https://myproject.com/api/file/:key`

where `:key` is the object key in the s3, that way i hide the s3 bucket to my user and the url is more friendly.

the result should be something like [this](https://via.placeholder.com/350x150) if i click the link, it opens a browser tab and display the image

i have tried this

```
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: Bucket,
    Key: Key,
  };
  const data = s3.getObject(s3Params).promise();
  res.download(data, 'file.jpg'); // does not work as the file is not in fs
  res.attachment(data) // does not work, i always get timeout
  res.sendFile(data) // same as download

  res.set('Content-type', mime); // the console show the response broken 
  res.send(data) // the console show the response broken and the page is blank
```

I also tried fetching the file from a signed url

```
const signingParams = {
    keypairId: Id,
    privateKeyString: Key,
    expireTime: expireTime,
  }
  // Generating a signed URL
  const signedUrl = cfsign.getSignedUrl(
    `https://${url}.cloudfront.net/${params.key}`,
    signingParams,
  );
  axios.get(signedUrl).then(({ data }) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png')
    res.send(data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

But the response return this [image]

How could i achieve this? i out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your screen. I believe the issue comes from NodeJs/Express but not S3 or AWS

The solutions to your issues can be partially found here [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs/40899767)

I made a small working version for you here, essentially piping the response directly

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded",
  responseType: 'stream'
})
  .then(function(response) {
    response.data.pipe(res)
});
```

https://runkit.com/qkhanhpro/test

Click on "endpoint" to test if the image will be displayed correctly

Comment: I have tried this and get the same result as image.

Comment: Try to create a sample like what I created above. I will look at the content an see where things go wrong