# Want to show the image that i get from db as by its name

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

SO my problem is images that i upload are set in the database and saves in vs code in uploads folder but i dont know how to display them on front end i have tried something but furthur needs to know the procedure

```
 <script>
                      
  axios
    .get(
      "http://localhost:8000/hotels")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
              document.getElementById('data').innerHTML+=`<tr class="odd">
                      <td class="dtr-control sorting_1" tabindex="0">${response.data[i].id}</td>
                      <td><img src='${response.data[i].image}'></td>
                      <td>${response.data[i].name}</td>
                      <td>${response.data[i].description}</td>
                      <td>${response.data[i].price}</td>
                      <td >${response.data[i].address}</td>`                                         
      }
     
  })
  
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

                      </script>
```

[So here you can see when i upload data the images are stored in the uploads folder All we need is to display image on front end somehow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rX1G.png)

Comment: you need to make sure the path to the upload folder is attached as prefix to the value of the img src.

Comment: how do i get the path and in what format i can make it upload to it can you show mw the exact link? I tried a lot but nothing happening

Comment: src='uploads/${response.data[i].image}' replace that with what you have in your src

Comment: tried it already but still no image

Comment: http://localhost:8000/admin/uploads/Screenshot%20(3).png 404 (Not Found)GET http://localhost:8000/admin/uploads/Screenshot%20(4).png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: probably this the error shown in console from the very first

Comment: okay, this is problem of directory, src='../../uploads/${response.data[i].image}', please try that, let see if it works

Comment: no this is not working i dont know wht but not working for me can you see it the errors

Comment: Well the error is gone

Comment: Image is not displaying but there is a black white space and nothing is showing

Comment: the error is gone after trying this src='../../uploads/${response.data[i].image}', ??

Comment: Error still resists sorry error still resists

Comment: You can do it i know we are close

Comment: can you share the new error you are facing?

Comment: GET http://localhost:8000/uploads/Screenshot%20(4).png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This is the error for all images

Comment: means for screenshot 3 it is

Comment: GET http://localhost:8000/uploads/Screenshot%20(3).png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: looking at the structure of your code you may have to replace your value in src to this src='../../../uploads/${response.data[i].image}'

Comment: Still same error uploads folder is not inside anyother folder its independent of other folders

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Unknown/Desktop/ecommerce_website/uploads/Screenshot%20(3).png         This is the link of the image that can be opened on chrome if we open

Comment: any issue you see till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /uploads folder is not hosted like other routes. you need to host it in order to resolve the URL.
[Here is how you can using express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

**EDIT**: Explanation
In your app.js/index.js(where you have initialized app())
write the code below

```js
const path = require('path')
app.use('/uploads',
  express.static(path.join(__dirname,
    'uploads')))
```

Also i believe the question is similar to [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs)

Comment: Solved the issue maaaaaaaan!!!!!!! Love you sardar g

Comment: @f180111YousafZahid Good job! Please make sure you mark this answer as Accepted !

Comment: how to do it? new to stack overflow

Answer (score -3):

You can use instead of

```
<td><img src='${response.data[i].image}'></td>
```

this line

```
<td><img src='${new URL("uploads/"+response.data[i].image, window.location.origin).toString()}'></td>
```

Comment: GET http://localhost:8000/uploads/Screenshot%20(3).png 404 (Not Found) same issue again with this code as well @hichaaaam

Comment: Let's try another way. Go to the upload folder, then open one of the images in that folder using Google Chrome or another browser. Then, send us the URL that you see.

Comment: ok let me do it file:///C:/Users/Unknown/Desktop/ecommerce_website/uploads/Screenshot%20(3).png

Comment: any issue you see till now?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't found another solution, but the image may not be accessible due to permissions or security restrictions. You should check to see if there are any permissions that you need to fulfill in order to access the image.

Comment: No issue brother, I dont think if there should eb any permission issue because its just a local host project running locally.There should be anything that i could possibly be missing but let me hit and trial it hope so it can come with a possible outcome